# Como concatenar ou utilizar o & comercial com data e texto?

Tags: vba, excel-vba

Estou a utilizar o seguinte código para que apresente apenas o dia e o mês.

```
Range("AB2").Select
ActiveCell.Value = "=Now()"
ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "yy/mm"
ultima_linha = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("AB2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("AB2:AB" & ultima_linha)
```

Pretendo que seja apresentado da seguinte forma: texto/**17/31**/texto.
Alguma ajuda sobre como popular os campos?

Answer (score 2):

Você pode formatar a data em uma variável e depois atribuir o valor na célula:

```
Dim data As String
data = Format(Date, "dd/mm")
data = texto1 & "/" & data & "/" & texto2
ActiveCell.Value = data
```

Comment: Não estou a perceber Ricardo!  Assim: data = "texto1 & " / " data & " / " & texto2"

Comment: Tenho que deferir as strings : texto1 = Ricardo; texto2 = Pontual;

Comment: Tens de definir as strings antes de utilizar

Comment: Continuo sem perceber! O valor data em duas vezes como uma string?

Comment: Como é que separo a variável "data" dentro da string?

Comment: @b8engl a motivação por trás de atribuir `data = texto1 & "/" & data & "/" & texto2`, ou seja, de atribuir à variável `data`, o valor de `texto1`, `texto2`  e novamente o valor da variável `data`, é diminuir a quantidade de memória ram utilizada na aplicação... Ele poderia ter feito `data_concatenada = texto1 & "/" & data & "/" & texto2`, no entanto, esse resultado seria alocado em outro endereço de memória, fazendo consequentemente o programa consumir mais memoria ram na hora de sua utilização.

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVIDO:

```
Range("AB2").Select
Dim tudo As String
data = Format(Date, "dd/mm")
tudo = "texto1/" & data & "/texto2"
ActiveCell.Value = tudo
ultima_linha = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("AB2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("AB2:AB" & ultima_linha)
```

Obrigado na mesma Ricardo Pontual!